# how to git merge with conflicts such that both changes are kept

Tags: git

I have two PRs that add code to the same file `f`.
in PR1, five lines of code are added at end of the file.  (on lines 101-105)
in PR2, six different lines are added at the end of the same file. (on lines 101-106)

so the file `f` has two different versions `PR1->a` and `PR2->b`

Now I want code in each PR to be compilable but they depend on each other.
Should I merge PR1 into PR2 first? or wait for pull into master?

If PR1 was actually merged, how should I get those changes into my PR2

Comment: you can use a git GUI like source tree https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/ which can easily help you in handling these changes interactively

Answer (score 1):

Pull request branches should not depend on one another. If PR1 is merged and this results in a merge conflict when PR2 is to be merged, simply resolve the conflict in whatever way makes sense for your code. (The web interface where the pull request is implemented, such as GitHub, will [supply an interface](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github) where you can do that.)

Answer (score -1):

As [matt points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68834365/1256452), the process of accepting the two merge requests (or "pull requests" as GitHub call them) goes one step at a time (because it must), so the problem you've described in your subject line hasn't actually come up yet.  When it *does* come up, it's pretty trivial to resolve in any editor.

It is, however, worth mentioning that merges in general *will* sometimes see merge conflicts of this form.  That is, we will see a conflict that can be described as:

- The user whose diff is shown on the left added lines A.
- The user whose diff is shown on the right added lines B.
- Both added lines are in the same region.
- I, the version control system, do not know which of these changes to take, and if I do take both, I do not know what *order to put them in*.

The kind of merge that takes *both sets of changes* is generally called *union merge*.  The top level `git merge` command does not have a union merge option, but `git merge-file`, which implements single-file merging—and which you can choose to run yourself when you encounter merge conflicts—*does* implement union merge.

The problem with union merge is that it *does not specfy which order to put the lines in*.  If the order literally doesn't matter, this "problem" is no problem after all, and you may use union merge.  If the order *does* matter, it *is* a problem, and you should not use union merge, which will pick an order at (apparent) random: there is therefore a 50% chance it will pick the *wrong* order.

If you can use union merge, simply  extract the three input files and use `git merge-file` to produce the correct result.  Where do you get the three input files?  They're in Git's *index* at the time of the merge conflict.  If you are using GitHub, rather than Git on your computer, to resolve the merge conflict, you probably do not have easy access to these files, and in any case, you almost certainly can't get them (GitHub) to run `git merge-file`, but if you are doing the merge locally, on your own laptop or whatever, use `git checkout-index` or `git show` to get the three files.

Note that `git checkout-index` has a special option designed to get all three input files at once: `git checkout-index --stage=all`.  This implies the `--temp` option, so you will have to read the output from `git checkout-index` to know which output file goes with which of the three inputs.  You can then run `git merge-file` with the `--union` option, and put the resulting file in at the right location and use `git add` to tell Git that the conflict is resolved.

See [the `git merge-file` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-file) for additional information, and remember that when there is a merge conflict, Git always leaves all the input files in its index ("the staging area") so that you can *resolve* the conflict.  *Your* job is to put the correct resolved result into your working tree, under whatever path name you want it to show up in, and run `git add` on that file.  If the path name is the same as the original path name—it usually is—this `git add` will erase the three input files *from* the index, leaving only the final result.

That is:

```
git merge somebranch
... (message about conflict in path/to/file.ext) ...

my-favorite-editor path/to/file.ext
<fix it up and write it out>

git add path/to/file.ext
```

The `git merge` step:

- failed, so left *three* copies of `path/to/file.ext` in the index;<sup>1</sup>
- left Git's own best-attempt-at-merging, with conflict markers, in the file named `file.ext` in the folder named `to` in the folder named `path` in your working tree;
- and stopped in the middle of the merge.

By running your editor on the working tree copy, and editing it to make it right, and writing it out, and running `git add`, you told Git:

- erase the three copies of `path/to/file.ext` from the index, and
- put in a new copy of `path/to/file.ext`, at stage zero ("resolved"), containing the same data as found in the file named `file.ext` in the folder named `to` in the folder named `path`.

That's what "resolving the conflict" really *means:* you just get the file ready for the next commit.  You likely, normally, every-day, do this *using* the best-effort file that Git left in your working tree.  But if that every-day manual process, using your editor, isn't satisfactory for some reason, you *also* have this "get me all three inputs, as is, from Git's index" method.  The `git mergetool` command is a thin wrapper around this "get me all three inputs, then run an editor on the three inputs; then, if the editor succeeds, run `git add` to declare the output correct" sequence.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that this is a *file* whose *name contains slashes*.  There are no *folders* involved.  That's how `path/to/file.ext` appears in Git's index; Git's index only holds files, not folders.